# Android EditText onClick Listener defined in Layout fails with obscure Exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-event

I want to define an onClick Listener for an EditText in the Layout-XML of may activity, but it always fails with an obscure Exception.

The Layout is injected with `setContentView()`in the `onCreate`-Method of my activity. I am **not** using a Fragment here and I am well aware that the XML defined `onClick` Listener do not work for fragments.

**For testing purposes I added the same handler method to an ImageView that is located next to the EditText. There the handler works, on the EditText it fails. So this is something special of the EditText and not a general Problem of a mislocated handler method.**

This is the relevant part of my layout file:

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
     android:layout_rowSpan="3"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_action_event"
     android:onClick="onCreationClicked"
     />

<EditText
     android:id="@+id/creation_edit"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
     android:hint="@string/enter_creation"
     android:onClick="onCreationClicked"
     style="@style/PickerEditText"
     />
```

When I click on the ImageView the associated method is executed and a DialogFragment is started. When I click on the EditText I get the following Exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onCreationClicked(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'creation_edit'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3994)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onCreationClicked [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3987)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I am currently testing on a Samsung S4 (Android 5.0.1) API 21 and AppCompat Library in Version v7 22.1.0

Adding the `onClick` Listener programmatically in the `onCreate` method would be a solution, but I wanted to avoid this, since it results in a single `onClick` method with a big switch statement and the XML-based onClick-Handler result in a more readable and explicit code which I prefer.

**Did additional research:**

Now I can reproduce the error behaviour and the correct behavior (see below). It seems this is a bug (or a feature) introduced with appcompat-v7 22.1.0 & 22.1.1.

I created a new fresh project with Android Studio with Blank Activity. minSdk 17, targetSdk 21. Added the `EditText` to the blank `Activity` as shown below and added the handler method to the `Activity` like this:

```
public void onCreationClicked(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Event Handled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Started the App touched the EditText --> Crash

Changed my build.gradle from:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
```

to

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

and the `Toast` is shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: I Need the onClick Listener on the EditText. Removing it is not a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this helps others to save time with searching for a solution. I raised an issue for appcompat7 which was accepted with the following comment:

> This has already been fixed for the next platform release, but it may not be feasible to fix this in appcompat.

Details:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=174871

So indeed it is a bug / problem of appcompat and I will fallback to adding the onClick listener programmatically.

Comment: i confirm, it's a bug:) happened to me just now, and the exception message is 'no such function'. bad google!

Comment: I just had this issue with `appcompat-v7:22.2.0`, went to the link and noticed a post an hour ago where the status had been changed to `FutureRelease`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the method `onCreationClicked(View)` in your `Activity` not in your `Fragment`. If you want the `Fragment` to handle the click, you need remove the `onClick` in your XML and handle the listener programmatically.

Comment: The Layout File is associated with an activity and the onCreatíonClicked is implemented in Activity. For testing purposes I added the same handler to the ImageView. There it works, but I want to have it on the EditText and not the ImageView. The only point where I use a Fragment here is that the "onCreationClicked" handler starts a DialogFragment.

Comment: did you removed the 'onclick' of the 'ImageView' when you test the 'onclick' in the 'EditText' ? maybe using the same method name is the pb.

Comment: why not just inflate the EditText in you onCreate() method and apply setOnClickListener on it ?

Comment: The onClick of the ImageView was only added for testing since the onclick in the EditText did not work. Adding a listener by `setOnClickListener` would be a solution, but then I would have 1 `onClick` listener method with a big `switch` statement since I have multiple clickable controls in my Activity and I wanted to avoid this, since the named `onclick`-Handlers are the better readable approach.

Comment: I just created a new fresh project and used the same code as yours and it's working for me even if I use the same onClick name for the ImageView and EditText. Android studio, minimum sdk 21 target 22. We need more info to help you

Comment: Edited the question, it is reproduceable with Minimum sdk 17 and target 21. If you change the appcompat version to 22.0.0 and less it works, with 22.1.0 and above it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following tip from #5 on [Issue 174871](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=174871):

change :
`<EditText .../>` 
to
 `<android.widget.EditText .../>`

So Appcompat does not handle onClick anymore

Comment: I don't think this is a solution at all. AFAIK this just means, that you are not using the appcompat EditText widget anymore by replacing it with the "native" Android widget. This means, that the behaviour and appearance of it, is dependant on the Android Version you are targeting. Appcompat is "emulating" the behaviour of newer Android version for older versions, so you will loose all "new" EditText features (which might be ok for you and an EditText).